# Add content between Wordpress queried posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am wondering how I can add something between posts being queried in Wordpress through this method:

```
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=name&showposts=2');
while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();?>
```

Is there a way I could add something simple, like say a `<hr>` between the two posts being pulled?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php $the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=name&showposts=2');
 while ($the_query->have_posts())
 {
 $the_query->the_post();
 echo '<hr />';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the response.. however now it only shows one post with the horizontal rule above it

Comment: i doubt so. the only change is that php code is now in the block. doesn't affect number of posts or anything.